# Window console applications will spawn new console

Tags: windows, console, system-administration

I've been running into some weird problems with some console apps that I use on windows (e.g python pip).

Some apps will run inline with the current console session, however some will spawn/fork a new process, run the command, print out to stdout then the results are copied back to the current session's stdout?

I haven't had this problem before, and is only relatively recent. Is it some weird windows config ?

Comment: Unlikely IMO.  More likely to be a problem with the executables in question.  For example, they might have been built as GUI-subsystem apps that explicitly create a new console if necessary, probably so that they don't cause an unnecessary console window to appear when double-clicked.

Comment: (The proper solution to that problem, by the way, is to have separate executables for console-mode and GUI-mode, so I suggest that you double-check that you're running the right one.)

Comment: Yeah that's probably the case... however it's a bit strange as to why this happen when going from python2->python3, they must of switched builds or something... I can understand it for MinGW apps though